# beginner to linq to entity sql: How do I write this linq to Entity query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
@Parameter = (some_value)
select * from C1
where C1.number = 
(select number from C2
where id = @Parameter)
```

pointers to good resources for learn the concepts of linq to entities will also be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following format:

```
var p = parameter;

from c in C1
where C.number == ( from x in C2
                   where x.id == p
                   select x).FirstOrDefault()
select c;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367.aspx) is the official MSDN documentation with examples for Linq To Entities.

Comment: Thanks. however C.number should be checked and not assigned using "=="

Comment: I've edited it.. that's just a typo. Does it work for your situation?

Comment: Just learnt that it can be done using lamda operation also as below:

var p = parameter;

from c in C1
where C.number == C2.Where(a => a.id == p).FirstOrDefault().number
select c;